# Weird network issue

Tags: sip, tcpdump

We are facing a technical issue with networking, which I'm not able to comprehend.

We are using Linphone Client to connect to x.x.x.125(Freeswitch box) via x.x.x.101 i.e .101 being a SIP proxy Flexisip.

The SIP flow look as below.

```
   [ Linphone box ]  <-> [ `.101` box ]  <-> [ `.125` box ]
```

Now when we register i.e SIP REGISTER request (without VPN connected) to .125 via .101 it works i.e Registration is a success, saying this because I was sniffing around the traffic with TCP dump on both .101 and Linphone Client box (both had 200 OK Response for Register request).

Now here is the deal, when we make a call i.e send SIP INVITE request without VPN connected. We see no traffic on .101 box but same can be found on Linphone box hinting that request is directed to .101.(but at the same time I can constantly see OPTIONS request appearing from .101 to Linphone Machine and also a 200K response getting sent from Linphone machine for OPTIONS request.)

Now, The sooner we connect to VPN, we see the request appearing on the .101 box from Linphone box

Now, had this behaviour would have stayed constant, I would have suspected the Firewall rule but the it would work during SIP REGISTER and not using Regular INVITE invite is something I'm able to understand here.

And when we are connected to VPN it work.

> NOTE: If I assume this is a packet loss as a part of UDP even the retransmission too does not go through and this happen in multiple run..
>
> It's only the INVITE packet would not be sent always does not happen with REGISTER request.

Here how the sip flow looks like

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the Linphone software could be getting confused by the multiple IP addresses. Try with a different softphone and see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: @sipwiz not just linphone I have also tested with our inbuild mobile app I see the Packet from mobile app destine to `.101` box but do see any packet on `.101` box side.

Comment: You will have to provide more information in order to get suggestions. The full REGISTER and INVITE requests with and without the VPN connected would be a good start. That will at least allow narrowing down whether it's a SIP issue or a networking one.

Comment: @sipwiz I will have that for you

Comment: Just wondering if you can control/inspect MTU setting on the network with/without VPN?

Comment: @sipwiz I have the pcap file how would you like have it.

Comment: Little thing I wanted to you to know In case of VPN I was not able to capture packet on the Client side (Linphone on android) since the Wireshark SSH connection was not reliable under VPN mode. **Hence I had to capture Packet from the SIP proxy side** when the phone was connected to VPN.

Comment: @Noobie can the pcap file be attached to the question? If not put it on a free file sharing site and add a link.

Comment: @sipwiz can you provide a confirmation were you able to get the files?

Comment: @Noobie yes I was able to download the files.

Comment: @sipwiz good thanks.. Lets hope we find something..

Comment: @Noobie the no vpn trace has not captured any packets from 63.211.239.125. It's hard to compare them without that. There are OPTIONS requests originating from .125 showing up in the trace so there are packets so perhaps you used different capture filters?

Comment: @sipwiz like I said the in case of no-vpn the the Tcpdump was captured using the SSH options in wireshark to the app running on android phone so all the packet like Options/INVITE/ etc would be directed from `63.211.239.125` to the android phone via `63.211.239.101` proxy. (**hence the reason you would not see any packet from `.125` box**, since they are relayed back to app via `.101`)


And since when I was connected to VPN ssh and checking the packet via wireshark was not reliable I had to tcpdump the packet on the sip proxy i.e `.101` box.

Comment: @sipwiz any luck here?

Comment: @Noobie everything I can guess at I've put in my answer. To help further I'll need a tcpdump run on the Proxy (.101) server for the non VPN attempt. The unknown is whether the Proxy is forwarding requests to the FreeSWITCH server when they arrive on it's public interface. The packet trace should reveal that.

Comment: @sipwiz I will get that for you. But as I mentioned I was not able to see any packet for INVITE on tcpdump side on `.101` on non VPN mode.

Comment: @Noobie the unexplained thing is that the OPTIONS requests that are being sent from the FreeSWITCH server on .125 to the softphone in the "no vpn" capture are in the trace but only the leg from the Proxy (on .101) to the softphone (10.1.10.1). That request had to get to the Proxy from .125 but it's not in the trace. Is the trace being run to capture on all the Proxy's interfaces?

Comment: @Noobie I think that because that those TCPDUMP are taken at 2 discrete timing.

Answer (score 4):

Given the REGISTER requests are getting through that rules out an IP routing and firewall issue (assuming it's not doing deep inspection on SIP packets).

That leaves the two most likely culprits as the client software (in this case Linphone) using the wrong network interface,

Try running a test with a tool like [sipp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) where you can explicitly set the local address to use and the type of SIP request to send.

```
# To test the user agent client scenario (which sends INVITE requests) use:
sipp -bind_local 10.1.10.1 -sn uac -m 1 x.x.x.125
```

**Update:**

Some observations from inspecting the packet captures:

In the no VPN case:

- there is a NAPT between the softphone and the Proxy translating `10.1.10.1` to `49.36.13.47`, e.g. `10.1.10.1:39248` mapped to `49.36.13.47:44150`.
- `REGISTER` responses do appear to be coming from the FreeSWITCH server at `63.211.239.125` according to the User Agent string of `Flexisip...` on the response.
- in agreement with the original post there are no responses at all to `INVITE` requests in the capture.
- there are no fragmented UDP packets captured.

In the VPN case:

- there is no NAPT between the softphone and the Proxy. The softphone traffic is originating from `172.17.8.37`.
- the softphone is using an IP address of `192.168.29.134` in it's SDP offer which means the device likely has multiple network interfaces.
- there is a fragmented UDP packet recorded when the softphone sends an `INVITE` request to the Proxy but it doesn't  seem to be an issue as the Proxy happily forwards the request to the FreeSWITCH server.

**Missing Data:**

The no VPN capture does not contain the traffic between the Proxy and the FreeSWITCH server. This is the most crucial leg for the analysis since it could show whether the Proxy is forwarding the INVITE request or not.

Running `tcpdump` directly on the Proxy would be able to provide this missing information.

**Updated Guess:**

Based on the still incomplete information my best guess would now be that that Proxy has misconfigured (or perhaps deliberate) SIP settings and is silently dropping `INVITE` requests received on public interfaces.

When the softphone connects on the VPN the `INVITE` requests are forwarded because they are considered to originate from an internal network.

For `REGISTER` requests the Proxy could have a rule that says always forward them no matter which interface the Proxy receives them on since they are not as risky as `INVITES`.

Comment: I won't be able to run that on an android device, until I root it :(

Answer (score 1):

If the path is different, the INVITE will go through different networks and they may not behave the same.

I can see 2 possible issues with the network used when VPN is not active:

- A NAT has an ALG which, being broken, would drop the INVITE and let the other ones go through. This is unlikely, because it's happening for several User-Agent your tried.
- The network is configured to drop packet larger than a specific size. This is very likely because the INVITE, with all User-Agent, is always the largest SIP message being sent.

I would advise you:

- Try TCP: This should confirm it's a UDP only issue.
- Try to remove all codecs and keep only PCMA, with UDP: if it works, it's likely a UDP/MTU/SIZE issue.

EDIT:

**To make it clear, you certainly have an MTU issue.**

Thus, I advise you to test your UDP network and the MTU size limit with and without the VPN. You don't have to use your android, but you need to use the same network.

On sip server, starts:

```
$> nc -u -l -p 2399
```

On LAN side, any PC with same network with netcat tool...

```
$> cat invite1000.example | nc -u sip.antisip.com 2399
$> cat invite1200.example | nc -u sip.antisip.com 2399
$> cat invite1500.example | nc -u sip.antisip.com 2399
$> cat invite2000.example | nc -u sip.antisip.com 2399
$> cat invite8000.example | nc -u sip.antisip.com 2399
```

Make several invitexxx.example files with any data, but with specific number of char in it.

In theory, nc/netcat on the server will stop receiving the packets when going over the MTU (or the packet will be incomplete).

Then, this will confirm it's an MTU issue.

Comment: I would agree to you on the MTU part had PSJIP (the library that is used internally) not had a limit check( limit check on 1500 MTU ). We are not seeing any error on PJSIP complaining our SIP INVITE request was above 1500 MTU

Comment: The mtu is not always 1500. The maximum allowed packet size if often lower (this is configured by network admin). A value of 1200 is usually the maximum to use if you want the packet to cross any network. Even some network only allow 1000...

Comment: we tested our working with VPN and there we don't seem to find any issue related to MTU

Comment: If you don't have packet size issue with VPN, it doesn't mean you don't have packet size issue wirhout VPN... Please test with netcat the udp size limit. It seems you didn't verified yet...